# Show new content count on the taxonomy term list view

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a view that lists the terms in a specific vocabulary. I can also mark the terms if there is a new content tagged with this term. My view looks like this:

> - Term 1
> - Term 2
> - Term 3 (new)
> - Term 4
> - Term 5 (new)
> - ...

However, what I would like to achieve is a view that shows the count of the new contents tagged with a term. Like this:

> - Term 1
> - Term 2
> - Term 3 (2 new)
> - Term 4
> - Term 5 (7 new)

My current views configuration is like following:

1. Showing taxonomy terms of a specific vocabulary
2. Added a relationship of **Taxonomy term: Content using *my vocabulary***
3. Added field **Content: Has new content**: This has caused duplicate rows for the terms that has more than one new content. For example, if a term has three new contents, it was listed three times. So I did the next step.
4. Activated **Aggregation**, and set the aggregations settings of the field **Content: Has new content** to **SUM**: This has solved the duplicate rows issue, but it doesn't show the sum of the contents as I actually wanted to achieve.

Is there any possibility that I can show the number of new contents on this view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution A: Use Views Field View**

Using the [Views Field View](https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module it is possible to embed the results of one view into another view.

First create a view for nodes without a page/block (you only need the master display) and name it **New content count by term**. Add a context filter *Content: Has taxonomy term ID*. Ensure that only the *Nid* is listed in the fields section, add the filters *Content: Published (Yes)* and *Content: Has new content*, then enable aggregation, choose *Count* from the *Aggregation settings* of the *Nid* field and finally remove any pagers.

[image: Settings for New content count by term view]

Now you may embed the **New content count by term** view into your principal view (taxonomy terms) by adding a "Global: View"-field (provided by the Views Field View module). In order to specify the tid-parameter of the embedded view, make sure that the Term id is also exposed as a field in the principal view. If you do not want to show it to the end user, just choose *Exclude from display* in the field settings. After the output of the tid field can be used as a parameter (token `[tid]`) for the embedded view.

**Solution B: Use hook_views_query_alter**

There is a function in the forum module responsible of returning the number of new posts on a topic (term) on behalf of a given user ([_forum_topics_unread](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!forum!forum.module/function/_forum_topics_unread/7)). Use this query as a starting point for your own implementation of [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7).

I recommend to go for solution A and only try to implement B when performance is degraded beyond acceptable limits.

Comment: Thanks for your answer znerol. I'd like to go for solution B, would you like to expand it a little bit?

Comment: I've succeeded it using the Solution A, even if it impacts the performance. I would be very glad if you could expand the solution B with some example about how to implement `hook_views_query_alter` to get the new node count.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. I think that solution B very much depends on the actual view. Therefore it is somewhat difficult to write up a short generic solution which is also relevant to other folks than you.

Comment: Ok, thanks though for the Solution A. I've awarded you the bounty. I'll perhaps start a new bounty for this question to get an answer for Solution B, which is better for performance.